# Where are the `tfds.load` datasets are saved?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I downloaded the `cats vs dogs` dataset using the `tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs')` and I want to find where it has been saved on my computer, after reading a bit I came across someone who claims the dataset can be found at `~/tensorflow_datasets/cats_vs_dogs/` but I can't find a folder that is called `cats_vs_dogs` at that path, how can I get the path to the files?

Comment: Usually it is stored in a working directory. It depends on the system and the configuration you use, also depends on what kind environment you use (virtual etc.). So to give you the specific path one would need more information, like operating system and so.

Comment: @StatTistician No virtual environment, working on Windows 10

Comment: Yeah, but this is not enough information. Depends on your Python setup and so....

Comment: Where is this dataset stored in google colab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per default

[image: ex1]

as I assume TFDS_DATA_DIR has not been set, datasets will be stored under ~/tensorflow_datasets

However, as this depends on your system and setup: If you want to check the dataset and see it, I would suggest to just manually set data_dir when using tfds.load. Then you know for sure, where it is stored.

Comment: I didn't know that `~` referenced `c:/users/<user>` so I looked at the `../site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/..` instead, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

tfds.core.get_tfds_path('cats_vs_dogs')
```

```
'C:/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/cats_vs_dogs'
```

Comment: I get this when I try to call `get_tfds_path`: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_datasets.core' has no attribute 'get_tfds_path'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a folder to download as :

```
data_dir = 'D:\\Sandbox\\Github\\DATA_TFDS'

tfds.load(name='mnist',
          split=['train', 'test'], 
          shuffle_files=True, 
          data_dir=data_dir, 
          with_info=True, 
          download=True)
```